# Copying white text from webpage

Tags: html, copy-paste

Our application is in a permanent nightmode with white text on a black background.
We recently upgraded to Windows 7. Now when users copy content out of the application, word 2010 keeps the white font.
Is there a style/attribute/element or other hack I could put on our content that Word can pick up and interpret as black text but browsers will ignore?

Comment: MS says:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/paste-plain-text-into-word-HA010215710.aspx

Comment: Your users are doing it wrong. You really shouldn't attempt to "fix" this issue. Although if you want to, you're going to have to do silly things.

Comment: I agree, but from the user's point of view the program was working fine before the Windows 7 upgrade, we did something and now functionality is broken.

Comment: You can use svg text and fill css property, that avoids being copied with the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with SVG and Fill CSS property.

CSS

```
text{
fill: white;
}
```

HTML (SVG)

```
<svg>
<text>This is some white text, but will be copied as black.</text>
</svg>
```

[JSFIDDLE so you can test and see how it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/x7xz4nk6/)

Comment: Hmm, seems to get caught up on html tags. I guess we could wrap each text section of the tags in svg/text.